# Why does my for loop stop after the first iteration? R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to automate the process of translating a questionnaire raw score to a percentile based on a table that references the normative population data.

These are my data frames:

```
id <- c(001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010)
age <- c(3.5, 4, 7, 8, 11, 4, 4, 6, 7, 3)
domain_score <- c(sample(12:53, 10))

pd_frame <- data.frame(id, age, domain_score)

norms_table <- data.frame(percentile = rev(c(1, seq(from = 5, to = 100, by = 5))),
                          score_start = c(46, 38, 36, 34, 33, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 19, 17, 15, 13, 12),
                          score_end = c(53, 45, 37, 35, 33, 32, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12))
```

In order to solve this issue I have created a for-loop where I am aiming to match the `domain_score` from the `pd_frame` to the score bins I have in the `norms_table`.

Then if the `domain_score` falls within a given range in the `norms_table`, I want to retrieve the `percentile` in the `norms_table` and add it to a new `percentile` column in the `pd_frame`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(pd_frame)) {
  current_score <- pd_frame$domain_score[i]
  bin_low <- norms_table$score_start[i]
  bin_high <- norms_table$score_end[i]
  current_percentile <- norms_table$percentile[i]
  if (current_score >= bin_low & current_score <= bin_high) {
    pd_frame$percentile[i] <- current_percentile[i]
  } else {
    pd_frame$percentile[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

This for-loop works for the 1st row in the `pd_frame` but it stops after that and I am not sure how to make it continue to iterate for the entirety of the `pd_frame`.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current for loop is not working as intended because the logic inside the loop is not correctly set up to iterate through norms_table for each domain_score in pd_frame. In your current setup, you are only comparing the ith domain_score with the ith row in norms_table, which is not the correct approach for this problem.

You need to modify your loop so that for each domain_score in pd_frame, it checks against all rows in norms_table to find the appropriate percentile. Here's how you can do it:

```
# Adding a new column for percentile in pd_frame
pd_frame$percentile <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(pd_frame)) {
  current_score <- pd_frame$domain_score[i]

  for (j in 1:nrow(norms_table)) {
    bin_low <- norms_table$score_start[j]
    bin_high <- norms_table$score_end[j]

    if (current_score >= bin_low && current_score <= bin_high) {
      pd_frame$percentile[i] <- norms_table$percentile[j]
      break  # Exit the inner loop once the correct bin is found
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise loops are probably the easiest to understand when you are first starting out, but hopefully these solutions will inspire you to explore the power of R further.

Loops are inefficient, particularly in with large data. R has much more efficient ways to create your desired output. To illustrate, here are the results of a `microbenchmark()` comparing your (corrected) loop, a `left_join()` from `dplyr`, and a `data.table` approach:

```
# Values in milliseconds
                   min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
forloop       8.671602 8.990551 9.685666 9.151901 9.374700 19.385501   100
left_join     3.601901 4.220801 4.485867 4.514701 4.642000  6.909702   100
data.table    1.963202 2.197301 2.342982 2.365251 2.465151  3.021801   100
```

As these results show, your loop is around two times slower than a `left_join()` and four times slower than using `data.table`.

Note that you will need to install both `dplyr` and `data.table` prior to running this code. If you want further explanation of how the code works, comment below.

The `dplyr` method:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- pd_frame %>%
  left_join(., norms_table, 
            by = join_by(domain_score >= score_start, 
                         domain_score <= score_end)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("score_"))

result
   id  age domain_score percentile
1   1  3.5           17         15
2   2  4.0           50        100
3   3  7.0           53        100
4   4  8.0           35         85
5   5 11.0           43         95
6   6  4.0           25         45
7   7  4.0           13          5
8   8  6.0           29         65
9   9  7.0           33         80
10 10  3.0           48        100
```

and here is the much faster `data.table` method. Note you have to convert your data to datatable first, but you can easily convert it back to a dataframe using `as.data.frame()`:

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to datatable
pd_dt <- as.data.table(pd_frame)
norms_dt <- as.data.table(norms_table)

result1 <- pd_dt[norms_dt, on = .(domain_score >= score_start, domain_score <= score_end), nomatch = NULL]
result1[,domain_score.1:=NULL]
result1 <- result1[order(id)]

result1
    id  age domain_score percentile
 1:  1  3.5           17         15
 2:  2  4.0           46        100
 3:  3  7.0           46        100
 4:  4  8.0           34         85
 5:  5 11.0           38         95
 6:  6  4.0           25         45
 7:  7  4.0           13          5
 8:  8  6.0           29         65
 9:  9  7.0           33         80
10: 10  3.0           46        100
```